# How can I sync default table model with table header?

Tags: java, swing

I have written action listener on column header that allowing  user to rename the selected column and add a new column.

Code to rename the column  -

```
int column = jTable1.getSelectedColumn();

            if (column == -1) {
                return;
            }
            boolean blag = true;
            String sColumnName = null;
            while (blag) {

                sColumnName = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(jTable1, "Enter Column Name", "Add Column", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);

                if (sColumnName == null) {
                    return;
                }
                if (sColumnName.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jTable1, "Column name can not be blank.");
                    blag = true;
                } else {
                    blag = false;
                }

            }
            int viewColumn = jTable1.convertColumnIndexToView(column);
            TableColumn tableColumn = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(viewColumn);
            tableColumn.setHeaderValue(sColumnName);
            jTable1.getTableHeader().repaint();
```

Code to add new column in JTable.

```
boolean blag = true;
            String sColumnName = null;
            while (blag) {

                sColumnName = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(jTable1, "Enter Column Name", "Add Column", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);

                if (sColumnName == null) {
                    return;
                }
                if (sColumnName.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jTable1, "Column name can not be blank.");
                    blag = true;
                } else {
                    blag = false;
                }

            }

            defaultTableModel.addColumn(sColumnName);
```

But the issue is when I rename the column and then add a new column, a new column is getting added but it show the old name of just renamed column.

How can I sync default table model with table header ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no API for renaming headers on the Default/TableModel. The options are to either subclass/implement a custom model or trick the default, something like this (pseudo-code):

```
Object[] headers = new Object[tableModel.getColumnCount()]; 
forEach (model-column)
    if (index == renamedColumn)
       headers[index] = newHeader
    else
       headers[index] = tableModel.getColumnName(index)
tableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(headers)
```

(Note: assumes identifier is same as name)

Comment: @trashgod - thanks for the edit, my netbook hicks on sssss :-)